# Output data from an input field as list elements in React fails - why?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, state

I am trying to output data from an input field as list elements. However, I always get the error message "addData is not a function" just before the finish line. Does anyone happen to have an idea where my error is? I have the feeling that the majority should be correct.
Thanks to all of you!

Heres my App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import Form from "/src/Form";
import { React, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [displayData, setDisplayData] = useState([]);

  const addData = (formData) => {
    setDisplayData([...displayData, { formData: formData }]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {displayData.map((data) => (
          <li data={data.formData} />
        ))}
      </ul>

      <Form formData={addData} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is my Form.js

```
import { React, useState } from "react";

const Form = ({ addData }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    addData(formData);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Hier kommt die neue Form:</label>
        <br />
        <input
          placeholder="Vor- und Nachname"
          type="text"
          value={formData}
          required
          onChange={(event) => setFormData(event.target.value)}
        ></input>
        <br />
        <input placeholder="Hausnummer und PLZ" type="text" required></input>
        <br />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 1):

The prop you're passing is called `formData`:

```
<Form formData={addData} />
```

But the component is expecting it as `addData`:

```
const Form = ({ addData }) => {
```

Change one to match the other.  Since the component already has a state variable called `formData`, it's probably easier to change the usage:

```
<Form addData={addData} />
```